# Correct way to do DataBinding in a WP7 UserControl

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7

I'm building a Windows Phone 7 App.  So, I'm using SilverLight 3(.7) and I'm having a bit of a problem with the UserControls that I've built.  Here's how I'm doing it now:

UserControl has a DependencyProperty named Number

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl" x:Name="myUserControl">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=Number}"/>
</UserControl>
```

To use it I'm simply doing:

```
<MyUserControl Number="{Binding ElementName=MyPage, Path=SomeNumber}">
<MyUserControl Number="{Binding ElementName=MyPage, Path=SomeOtherNumber}">
```

This all works great, but if I add a name to one of the two instances of my control, things go wacky.  For example:

```
<MyUserControl x:Name="SomeNumberControl"
               Number="{Binding ElementName=MyPage, Path=SomeNumber}">
<MyUserControl Number="{Binding ElementName=MyPage, Path=SomeOtherNumber}">`
```

Then the data doesn't show up.  It appears that the name given overrides the name specified in the UserControl and the bindings don't work.

So, I tried to do binding through the datacontext. And setting the DataContext to the UserControl.

so, my control became:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl" 
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">  
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
</UserControl>
```

With this nothing gets bound.  It's like the datacontext is never set and even weirder when I put this control in another user control that I created, It appears that the parent control is now somehow bound to the MyUserControl instance.

So when I do the following:

```
<MyPage>
    <MyUserControl Number={Binding SomeNumber}"/>
```

I get the error,

SomeNumber not found in type MyUserControl.

It's as if the binding for the parent control is now the instance of MyUserControl.  Am I just doing something fundamentally wrong in how I'm doing bindings in my user control, or is this something strange with SilverLight 4 and WP7.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Michael,

Thanks for your post, I am running into the **SAME** exact issue.  When I give my usercontrol an x:Name the databinding stops working.  

Unfortunately, I dont understand what you mean by  **I changed the references all to be named references and it works now**

Could you please elaborate.

Thanks :)

Comment: `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` is a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DependecyProperty in your codebehind called Number you can set

```
DataContext = this;
```

That should allow you to bind directly to your Number property from TextBlock.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that as well.  Same thing, it seems to ignore that I'm binding to this, either in XAML or in C#.

Comment: Do you get any binding exceptions (check the Output window).

Comment: I think I may have figured it out.  I was using DataContext at various places to do my binding.  Since I'm using a UserControl and not a window, it is part of the display tree of whatever page or window it is instantiated, and it inherits the datacontext.  This can overwrite the datacontext, especially if you set it in the constructor.  I changed the references all to be named references and it works now.

Comment: That's... terrible.  If you're using MVVM, your UserControl's DataContext should be the Model (or similar) that it is designed for.  Even if you're not, it is "surprising behavior" that your UC's DC is *not* inherited, and refers back to itself.